# Specification of permutation design in RDA

Tags: multivariate-analysis, permutation-test, nested-data, vegan

I am using RDA to study plant communities in various land uses (variable *LU* with values M, U, etc.). For each land use, I sample 3 to 5 fields (M1, M2, U1, U2, etc). I make 5 measurements for both plant communities and environmental variables in each field.
I repeat the process every 6 months to study the effect of time and season (D16 for dry season 2017, R16 for rainy season 2016, etc). For *field* M1 for instance, I have the values for the *field_in_season* M1-D16, M1-R16, M1-D17.

My 5 measurements are interdependent; and there is also temporal dependance for the *field_in_season* within the *fields*.

When I want to test the significance of my RDA, I should thus constrain the permutation to take this into account.

If I am correct (if not please tell me so), in linear models I should write :

```
> lme(Y ~ X, random = ~1|Field/Field_in_season)
```

From various reads, I understand that in RDA I should not only use the `strata = Plot` argument, but allow for permutation of measurements within *field_in_season*, and for permutations among *field_in_season*. So that would be :

```
> rda_repeated = anova(rda(Community~LU + Humidity, data = env), by = 'term', permutation = how(within = Within(type = "free", mirror = TRUE),  plots = Plots(strata = Field_in_season, type = "free")))
```

Is that right ? In the output I get very similar results and “Permutation : free” in both cases, which dos not seem right. Beside I don't see how I can add the dependance within one field sampled at different seasons.

————————————————————————
————————————————————————

Here is a code sample :

```
> Community = matrix(ncol = 10,nrow = 1350)
> colnames(Community) = letters[1:10]
> for (i in letters[1:10]){
>  Community[,i] = rpois(135, 3)
}
> head(Community)
     a b c d e f g h i j
[1,] 3 2 1 1 4 5 4 2 4 4
[2,] 2 2 5 4 0 4 4 2 1 3
[3,] 9 2 3 3 1 4 2 3 1 3
[4,] 4 1 2 3 3 4 3 5 2 3
[5,] 1 1 4 4 1 2 4 8 3 5
[6,] 0 4 6 3 6 3 1 2 3 2

> Season = rep(c('D16', 'R16','D17'), each = 450)
> LU = rep(c('M', 'U', 'O'), each = 15, length.out = 1350) 
> Field = paste(LU, rep(c(1:3), each = 50), sep = '')
> Field_in_season = paste(Field,Season, sep = '-')
> Humidity = rnorm(n=1350, mean = 100)
> env = data.frame(Season, LU, Field, Field_in_season)
> head(env)

 Season LU Field Field_in_season
1    D16  M    M1          M1-D16
2    D16  M    M1          M1-D16
3    D16  M    M1          M1-D16
4    D16  M    M1          M1-D16
5    D16  M    M1          M1-D16
6    D16  M    M1          M1-D16



> library(FactoMineR)

> anova(rda(Community~LU + Humidity, data = env), by = 'term’)                    # Without specification for permutations

> anova(rda(Community~LU + Humidity, data = env), by = 'term’,                    # With restricted permutations
    permutation = how(within = Within(type = "series", mirror = TRUE), 
    plots = Plots(strata = Field_in_season, type = "series"),
    blocks = Field))


Permutation test for rda under reduced model
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
Permutation: free
Number of permutations: 999

Model: rda(formula = Community ~ LU + Humidity, data = env)
           Df Variance      F Pr(>F)    
LU          2   0.4427 9.7954  0.001 ***
Humidity    1   0.0283 1.2508  0.247    
Residual 1346  30.4150                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```